# How can i find the predefined button class Windows 8 apps using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How can i find the predefined button class  Windows 8 apps using JavaScript?

For example

```
 <button id="playlistBackButton" class="win-backbutton">Back</button>
```

"win-backbutton" it is a predefined Back button class . I need all other predefined  buttons class like Next,play, previous buttons. I searched my whole project but i can't find the  class. Is anyone know Where is the button class located ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the definition for `win-backbutton` in two files in your project.  There are styles for the light and dark theme.

These files are located here:

[image]

```
/References/Windows Library for JavaScript 1.0/css/ui-dark.css
/References/Windows Library for JavaScript 1.0/css/ui-light.css
```

The files do not appear to define any of the classes such as Next, Play, Previous.

However, it looks like the class definition just uses the symbols from the `Segoe UI Symbol` font. You should be able to do the same and define your own styles (Next, Play, Previous) using that same font.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this font [IcoMoon.ttf](https://github.com/aozora/bootmetro/blob/master/content/font/IcoMoon.ttf).  In this font contains all metro style icons and use your own icons